# Spring @Trasactional is not rolling back while there is an exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, transactions

I am new to spring and working on a sample program using Spring jdbc. this is to check how spring @Trsactional working and rolling back the changes to the Db if there is an exception.

But I am not able to achieve this. Through I am raising an exception in one of the DB update, still it's inserting the data to DB and not rolling back.

I know somewhere I am making mistake but not able to figure it out. Not sure if this is a correct approach.

What I am doing :-

1. in main methis I am calling load methos of Global class (which has jdbcTemplate as satic member as I will this jdbcTemplate to all other classes)
2. Global class load methos will initiate the bean using ApplicationContext.
3. Creating Dbclass instance in main method and sending the jdbcTemplate as parameter.

4.creating some sample data and calling executeDb method.

5.execute DB method will create the instance of other Dbclasss and setting the jdbcTemplate which earlier I initialized using bean in main method (I have separate class for each operation - like createuser, UpdataBalance etc)

6. then it will call the db opration method to insert data (I am using batchupdate)

> **EDIT - Removed all try-catch**

**DB opration code:-**

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
    public void executeDB(int count) throws Exception
    {

                CreateAccount newacc = new CreateAccount(jdbcTemplate);
                CreateUser newusr = new CreateUser(jdbcTemplate);
                //BalanceUpdate newbal = new BalanceUpdate(jdbcTemplate);
                newacc.addList(acclist);
                newusr.addToList(usrlist);
                //newbal.addList(ballist);

                newusr.execute(); // insert data to db
                newacc.addAccount(); // insert data to db
                //newbal.addBalance(); // insert data to db

                newacc.getAccList().clear();
                newusr.getUserList().clear();
                //newbal.getBalanceList().clear();
                if(count == 5000)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    throw new Exception("Rollback");
                }
                count += 1000;
                //throw new Exception();


        }
```

```xml
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"></context:component-scan>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="system"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
    </bean> 

    <bean id="startit" class="com.example.springtransaction.GlobalClass">  
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
    </bean> 
<bean id="dbupdate" class="com.example.springtransaction.DbUpdate">  
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
</bean>
```

Comment: Have you tried `@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class})`

Comment: @Raizuri yes but that didnt help.

Comment: Your code is absorbing the exception. Remove the try-catch block.

Comment: What if instead of @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class}) you do @Transactional (rollbackFor = Throwable.class)

Comment: @user7005835 - no difference.

Comment: @Rajarshi : Did you try after removing try-catch block?

Comment: @Sanj I ahve removed and tried. didnt work, still it's updating the details in DB

Comment: @Bozho I came to know that you are a Java/Spring expert. Will you be able to help me to find where I making the mistake and how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to throw exception from your method not silently log it in catch block.
And for checked exceptions you need to use `@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class})`.
http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/transactional-roll-back/
https://www.catalysts.cc/en/wissenswertes/spring-transactional-rollback-on-checked-exceptions/

Comment: @Rajarshi Did you removed `try{} catch(Exception e){}` completely from your method and added `public void executeDB() throws Exception`?

Comment: yes I removed all try-catch and added throws on executeDB, still not working

Comment: sorry for a very late reply, but still I am not able to fix it, will you be able to point out any further possible mistake. I thought it was working fine but I made a small mistake in calculating the result while made me thing it's working

Comment: @Rajarshi, could you please update your code in the question? It says **EDIT - Removed all try-catch** but `try{} catch{}` is still there.

Comment: I have also added the github url for the project. I guess it will help to identify the issue easily

Comment: Could you please try to remove definitions of `DbUpdate` and `GlobalClass` from XML and use annotations instead? I see `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example"></context:component-scan>` in XML but no classes annotated with `@Bean/@Component/@Repository/@Service` in that package (and child packages).

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the try - catch and define that the method throws an Exception. Something like that

```
    @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class}) 
    public void executeDB() throws Exception
    {
       if(usrlist.size() >= 5) 
       { 
           CreateAccount newacc = new CreateAccount(jdbcTemplate);
           CreateUser newusr = new CreateUser(jdbcTemplate);
           BalanceUpdate newbal = new BalanceUpdate(jdbcTemplate);
           newacc.addList(acclist);
           newusr.addToList(usrlist);
           newbal.addList(ballist);
           newusr.execute(); // insert data to db
           newacc.addAccount(); // insert data to db
           newbal.addBalance(); // insert data to db - raise exception here 
        }
    }
```

**Update**

The class that contain the executeDB() method should be a @Component and inject that component in the main class. 
Not create a new Dbclass() instance by your own.

In high-level the reason is that the Spring creates proxy classes upon injection for classes that declare **@Transactional**.
You could read more about [Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop) here.

Comment: I have removed all try-catch, still it's not working

Comment: How do you call that method? You should call that from an injected bean.

Comment: I mean this method should be in a @Component and inject that component in the main class. Not create a new Dbclass() instance by your own.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in checking the actual details in Db. but unfortunately it's not rolling back. For example I have thrown an exception after inserting 5000 recoreds, but it's not rolling back to 4900.